# Ajax HTTP request interceptor, adding a header value after upon promise.resolve is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, http-headers

I'm trying to parse the authorization header in my HTTP requests via the ajax interceptor

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    oauth.getCurrentToken().then((token) => {
      console.log(token); // gets logged for all my requests
      xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header2', 'test2'); // doesn't work

    });
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'test1'); // work
  }
});
```

However, I can see that x-my-custom-header is getting added to my request, while x-my-custom-header2 is not.

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
x-my-custom-header: test1
```

oauth.getCurrentToken() is basically a service that I have and it would resolve a token object after retrieving it from the localStorage.

The reason why I need to do getCurrentToken() before parsing it is that because the value may change from time to time so I need to always parse the latest token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `beforeSend` is synchronous so the promise `then()` won't fire before request gets sent

You probably need to create your own ajax service function so you can resolve `getCurrentToken()` before the request options are created

Something like:

```
function doAjax(url, data, type = 'get') {    
  return oauth.getCurrentToken().then((token) => {
    return $.ajax({
      url,
      data,
      type,
      beforeSend: (xhr) => xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header2', token);
    });    
  });
}

// usage
doAjax('somePath', {foo:'bar'}, 'post').then(res=> console.log(res))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a global ajax setup that is async ?

Comment: Also one more question, what if I want to pass an object as an argument that would hold the other properties that we can use? For example processData, contentType etc...
Also it is not clear why you do url, data,type, that would hold the values no?
did you mean url: url, data: data, type: type ?

Comment: Those properties are allowed in ES6 de-structuring but are same as `url:url` which is safer for full browser support. You could have an `options` argument and do somthing like `const opts = $.extend({beforeSend:(xhr)... }, options)` ... `return $.ajax(opts)`