# Fetch token from api and Intercepting ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am trying to get token from api and wanted to send each ajax call in jquery.

```
function fetchToken(){
      // duplicate backend call by `delay` returns a promise
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve('test');
        }, 500);
    });
    }
function interceptAjaxCall(){
 var ajaxReference = $.ajax;
  $.ajax = function (options) {
      fetchToken()
      .then(function (tokenfrombackend) { 
          console.log(tokenfrombackend);
          var success = options.success;
          options.headers = { 'token':tokenfrombackend}; //this does not set token in each ajax call header!
          options.success = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (success)
              success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
          };
         //return ajaxReference .apply($, arguments); /*returning here fails ajax call*/
      })
               
      return ajaxReference.apply($, arguments); 
    }
```

Intercepting each ajax is working but does not set token in each ajax header even after getting token value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax HTTP request interceptor, adding a header value after upon promise.resolve is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436474/ajax-http-request-interceptor-adding-a-header-value-after-upon-promise-resolve)

Comment: @ikhvjs, Tried but not working as expected!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried from the suggested question?